# Why is there a difference in who sent messengers to the King of Edom vs. Sihon

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, chukas

In [Bemidbar 20:14](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=264) **Moshe** sends messengers to the King of Edom. But, in [Bemidbar 21:21](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=280&hilite=), **Yisra'el** sends messengers to Sihon, King of the Emori.

Why this difference? Who is meant by stating **Yisra'el** in the second case - is it the heads of the tribes?

Answer (score 1):

Rash"i on Bemidbar 21:21 says that they are essentially conveying the same idea and one "supplements the other". I.e., the leader of a generation is considered as if he were the entire generation.